# Future function is giving null

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to call a future function which fetches a array from one of my firebase document's collection. I want to pass that array to a new firebase query to match the user data but the future function is giving null value on every collection I try I don't know why. I have tried many changes in my future function sometimes one of them works but temporarily like for a couple of prints in debug log only.

Here's my future function:

```
List<dynamic> gotclientcodes = [];

  Future getclientcodes() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        gotclientcodes = value.data()!['clientcode'];
      });
    });
  }
```

Also please let me know if the value I will get from `gotclientcodes` will work on this stream query?

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("capitalbalances")
            .where('clientcode', arrayContains: gotclientcodes)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
```

Comment: Can you share database screenshot

Answer (score 0):

In your first function, try adding in your code: *await*.

The result will be something like this (may work):

```dart
List<dynamic> gotclientcodes = [];

  Future getclientcodes() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        gotclientcodes = value.data()!['clientcode'];
      });
    });
  }
```